# Node JS Sequelize where clause on the pivot table of many-to-many relationship is fetching all the records

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am building a Node JS application. I am using Sequelize for the database. Now, I am having a problem using where clause on pivot table in a many-to-many relationship.

I have the game model with the following code:

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Game extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
      Game.belongsToMany(models.Team, {
        through: models.GameTeam,
        as: "Teams",
        foreignKey: "game_id"
      })
    }
  };
  Game.init({
    title: DataTypes.STRING,
    registration_deadline: DataTypes.DATE,
    start_at: DataTypes.DATE,
    end_at: DataTypes.DATE,
    location: DataTypes.STRING,
    latitude: DataTypes.FLOAT,
    longitude: DataTypes.FLOAT
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Game',
  });
  return Game;
};
```

Then I got another model, Team with the following code.

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Team extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
      Team.belongsToMany(models.Game, {
        through: models.GameTeam,
        as: "Games",
        foreignKey: "team_id"
      })
      Team.belongsToMany(models.User, {
        through: models.UserTeam,
        as: "Users",
        foreignKey: "team_id"
      })
    }
  };
  Team.init({
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    status: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    game_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    creator_id: DataTypes.INTEGER
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Team',
  });
  return Team;
};
```

As you can see game and team have a many-to-many relationship.

Then I get another model called, User with the following code.

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class User extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
      User.hasMany(models.VerificationToken, { foreignKey: 'userId', as: "verificationTokens", onDelete: 'cascade' });
      User.belongsToMany(models.Role, {
        through: models.UserRole,
        as: "Roles",
        foreignKey: "user_id"
      })
      User.belongsToMany(models.Team, {
        through: models.UserTeam,
        as: "Teams",
        foreignKey: "user_id"
      })
    }
  };
  User.init({
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING,
    verifiedAt: DataTypes.DATE
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'User',
  });
  return User;
};
```

As you can see User and Team also have a many-to-many relationship. Now, I am trying to fetch all the games that have a relationship with a user through the team. The following is my query/ code.

```
let user = await User.findOne({
        where: {
          id: {
            [Op.eq]: user_id
          }
        }
      })

      let playerTeams = await user.getTeams();

      if (playerTeams.length < 1) {
        return {
          error: false,
          data: [ ]
        }
      }

     let games = await Game.findAll({
        where: where,
        order: order,
        include: [
          {
            model: Team,
            as: "Teams",
            through: {
              where: {
                team_id: {
                  [Op.in]: playerTeams.map(item => {
                    return item.id
                  })
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      })
```

When I run the code, it is fetching all the games does not matter which user they belong to. What is wrong with my code and how can I fix it?